# Increase space between textboxes using CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, margin

I want to increase the space between two textboxes without using the line break. I've created a CSS rule but it has no effect when displaying the page.

These are the textboxes

```
<asp:Label ID="Discount" CssClass="textboxcontainer" runat="server" Text="Discount: "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDiscount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="TotalAfterDis" CssClass="textboxcontainer" runat="server" Text="Total : "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTotal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />
```

I have this CSS rule in CSS file

```
div#page  .textboxcontainer{
    margin: 10px auto;
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Post the HTML, not the ASP.

Comment: @j08691, he writes the asp, not html

Comment: @JNF - The ASP is irrelevant here. Only the rendered markup matters. I also see no element with the ID of `page`.

Comment: @j08691, contrary. the rendered html is generated by .net, the OP has nothing to do with it

Comment: @j08691, one might say the html is relevant for the answer, but not for the question.

Comment: thank you guys I was adding the class to the label instead of the text box.

Comment: is there a CSS rule that can substitute the line break ?

Comment: The <br /> tag right after the textbox

Answer (score 0):

`margin` doesn't work on `asp:label`, since `asp:label` is rendered into `span`, which is an `inline` element

Try adding `display:inline-block` to your css rule.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<asp:Label>` will render as an HTML `span`, which displays `inline` by default, causing top and bottom `margin` to be ignored.  Add `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to your `.textboxcontainer` rule.

Comment: How's the different from the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

ASP Label controls render in a `<span>` tag at runtime. This is what is giving you trouble. Simply wrap the label and textbox control in their own div and you will get that block separation. Add a class to that div and give it a margin-bottom: XXpx  and you are on your way

```
         <div class="form-group">
             <asp:Label ID="Discount" CssClass="textboxcontainer" runat="server" Text="Discount: "></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDiscount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>            
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <asp:Label ID="TotalAfterDis" CssClass="textboxcontainer" runat="server" Text="Total : "></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTotal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
         </div>
```

CSS

```
.form-group{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```